# How to fix erro while running sth-comet?

Tags: fiware, fiware-sth-comet

I am trying to install and configure STH-Comet, but I am having difficulties and I could not solve it.

I'm following the existing tutorial. And some errors occur in the process. I would like your help if possible.

After cloning the repository and entering the directory, when I run the command: npm install, two situations occur:

1- If it is not as root the errors are presented:

[image]

2 - If it is as root the errors increase, they are:

[image]

I also tried to install and configure via rpm. I do not have the above errors, but when I run ./bin/sth the following error appears.

```
`` `/opt/sth/node_modules/logops/lib/logops.js:27
  let opts = merge({
      ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/sth/lib/sth.js:27:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)` ``
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me share the procedure I follow, in the case it helps.

- It has been done in a CentOS 7.5.1804 system.
- Asumming MongoDB is up and running in that system.
- All command runs as not privileged user (i.e. I'm not root)

Node environment (installed through [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)):

```
$ node --version
v8.15.1
$ npm --version
6.4.1
```

First, download the code:

```
git clone https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet.git
```

Then, install packages:

```
cd fiware-sth-comet
npm install
```

Next, edit `config.js` to configure STH (look STH for details about this file). I have used `config.js` "as is" from the repository.

Finally, run the service:

```
npm start
```

If log shows a message like this, then it has been started correctly:

```
time=2019-04-29T20:12:18.745Z | lvl=INFO | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=OPER_STH_SERVER_START | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | comp=STH | msg=Server started at http://localhost:8666
```

You can check it's running with a "dummy" request. For instance:

```
curl -H 'fiware-service: foo' -H 'fiware-servicepath: bar' 'localhost:8666/STH/v1/contextEntities/type/myType/id/myEntity/attributes/temperature?hLimit=3&hOffset=0&dateFrom=2017-10-16T00:00:00.000Z&dateTo=2017-10-26T23:59:59.999Z'
```